# Archive error: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" xcode 13.4

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, project, archive

I got this error from my old project when I try to archive my ios via xcode.

Specs:

- Monterey 12.1
- XCode 13.4.1
- Flutter 2.0.2

I was try update to `sonoma, flutter 3.16.x & xcode`. but, i got more errors. So, I want archive it without update my spec. cause I just want to delete 1 feature of my code and then upload to App Store.